# A new way to cut a pizza

Tags: mathematics, geometry, tiling

Can you cut a pizza (circle) into 12 **congruent** pieces, such that half of them have crust (circle boundary), while the other half do not? The pieces must have the same shape and area, but can be mirrors of each other.

**Bonus:** Can you do it with identical pieces, where pieces are not mirrors of each other?

Comment: For the record I like my pizza with crust :)

Comment: I've always loved this question. There are in fact many solutions, but I'll let others have a go at it before I post an answer. Do you allow answers where pieces have one point on the boundary?

Comment: By identical do you mean congruent or are you disallowing mirror images?

Comment: I dare you to put this into your "additional instructions" when ordering a pizza.

Comment: "No, they can't be identical while half have crust and half don't."

Comment: I've added a bonus question for identical pieces.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I meant that interior pieces are allowed to have one point on the boundary.

Comment: By any chance, did you read "Things to make and do in the 4th dimension" by Matt Parker? ;)

Comment: Here is the same question from math stack exchange that may be of interest (although without the specification of 12 pieces): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481527/slice-of-pizza-with-no-crust

Comment: @QBrute I literally asked the exact same question in a comment before seeing it was posted already ;)

Comment: I can't post an answer (insufficient reputation), but I do have a somewhat oblique answer, based on an ancient cake-cutting riddle. I propose making three straight cuts to create six identically-shaped pizza slices ... and then one additional cut in the _horizontal_ plane to divide those six into 12. The top six will have topping, the bottom six will not. This _might_ be acceptable if (baked dough === crust) even if not at the edge of the original pizza.

Comment: I will just drop this here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_sMmuKPrnY&ab_channel=TheAxisofAwesome

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03794) by Joel Haddley and  Stephen Worsley answers a slightly different question - finding monohedral disc dissections where not all pieces touch the centre - but the results generally apply to this problem too.

My favourite answer is this one:

> [image]

Note that this one has interior pieces that don't even have a single point on the boundary.

There is an infinite family of solutions, that interpolates between [sybog64's solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/112067/20814) and the one above:

> [image]

The paper also shows some neat variations of [loopy walt's solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/112070/20814):

> [image]

Comment: Neat, indeed...

Comment: Love these constructions. It's great to see that interior pieces can have no points on the boundary.

Comment: Some of those are going to be pretty tricky to slice and serve!

Comment: This might be very useful for gerrymandering…

Answer (score 35):

This is a minor upgrade on @sybog64's answer:

> [image]

One way of thinking about it is to start with this

> [image]

configuration and then taking groups of 2 slices and rotating each group by 120°.

Comment: Just to confirm for your first picture: I could construct it from 18 identical arcs, each with a length of 1/6 the circle's circumference?

Comment: @JoelRondeau yes, exactly.

Comment: This is correct and answers the bonus question. Well done!

Comment: So assuming I have simple kitchen things, how do I slice my pizza thus? The radial cuts through the center are easy enough (butcher's twine to find the center of the pizza and get the radius. Pick a point on the edge to be a pivot for the folded string, and mark an arc with a pizza cutter from the crust to the center of the pizza. Move the string's pivot to where the crust edge was cut, and repeat until 6 arcs are cut). I don't know how to easily find the other pivot points, though.

Comment: @DewiMorgan I'm not fluent with advanced kitchen implements but geometrically the circle centres for the remaing 6 arcs can be obtained by rotating the centre of the pizza 30° around each of the corners of the large hexagon.

Comment: The "bonus question" is added **after** this answer has been posted ... what kind of bonus is that.

Comment: Yes sorry, the original question had a mistake. It said identical when I really wanted to have congruent. Then I realised we can  have identical too, so added the bonus question. Anyway both answers are great, but I can only accept one.

Comment: @loopywalt "then taking groups of 2 slices and rotating each group by 120°" I prefer to think of it as mirroring them, as two pieces form a symmetrical shield shape. With this point of view you don't have to do all 6 pairs at the same time.

Comment: Interesting images. What tool did you use to create it?

Comment: @JikkuJose https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: This looks to be the same as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w03ah.png) from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/481702) on math.SE.

Comment: @DewiMorgan All you need is a 12-pieces-where-6-pieces-don't-have-any-crust pizza cutter. You don't have one? It's a must for every kitchen.

Comment: @user253751 Oh, is THAT what those things are for? Yeah, turns out I've got three of them, but they've wedged the drawer shut, so I can't get to 'em. Guess I'm still looking for other solutions, then...

Answer (score 30):

I haven't found a perfect solution, my pieces are symmetrical but not identical

> [image: layout of the cut pizza]

> the pizza is first cut in 6 pieces following an arcs centered on the corner of the last cut piece with radius same as the pizza.
>  the 6 pieces are then cut along their axis of symmetry to get one crusty and one crustless piece

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. I hadn't realised that identical probably means that mirror images are not allowed. I do know of just one solution without mirror images though.

Comment: Somehow I like this answer more than the other (which is more "correct") ...

Comment: This is correct and well done!

Comment: I got the puzzle from here, which shows an actual pizza sliced in this way: https://news.liverpool.ac.uk/2016/01/12/mathematicians-reveal-new-way-to-slice-pizza-equally/